# Problema con apertura puertos Java

Tags: java, tcp, puertos

estoy aprendiendo java y probando a hacer un chat escrito tipo Cliente-Servidor usando TCP, que funcionara online, el caso es que lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora funciona muy bien en local, pero al poner una dirección de ip remota el cliente se conecta muy bien al servidor por que se que puerto tiene que estar abierto, ¿pero cuando el servidor tiene que enviar algo a los clientes como se que puertos usar que estén abiertos para conexiones remotas?, Por que yo por ejemplo en mi router solo tengo abierto el puerto que mi servidor utiliza para escuchar, o ¿como podría abrir los puertos de los clientes?

Answer (score 1):

Vale creo que he podido encontrar el error en mi código y es que tenia el socket cerrado, de todas formas os expongo el caso para verificar si una conexión de esta forma sería correcta para un uso real: Teniendo el servidor escuchando cuando se conecta un cliente este crea un socket entre cliente y servidor que se mantendrá abierto hasta que el cliente se desconecte y por donde viajara toda la información que el cliente y el servidor deban intercambiar

Answer (score 0):

El servidor es el programa que tiene los puertos abiertos, escuchando. **El cliente es el que inicia la comunicación**.

Cuando en un sistema los elementos pueden actuar a la vez como clientes y servidores, se denomina *Peer-to-Peer* (P2P).

El principal problema de estos sistemas no es informar de las IPs/puertos (basta con que los "clientes" envien un mensaje al "servidor" informando de qué puertos tienen abiertos) sino que normalmente el cliente no accederá directamente desde internet, sino que estará en una red local, por lo que tendrá que configurar NAT/Firewall para que la comunicación sea posible. Si se trata de un cliente doméstico, probablemente no tendrá ni idea de cómo hacerlo; si se trata de una empresa, posiblemente el departamento de IT no tendrá muchas ganas de hacerlo porque cada puerto abierto es un riesgo de seguridad.

Lo más sencillo es hacer que tus clientes se conecten regularmente a tu servidor para ver si hay nueva información, y que en la respuesta el servidor les proporcione la información que necesitan. Esa técnica se llama *polling*.

Comment: La teoría la entiendo, pero como es la primera vez que toco redes me surgen un par de dudas: primero, como hago para que mi cliente reciba información del servidor si este no se la envía, solo he visto ftp asi que como mucho se me ocurre que el servidor ponga dicha información en un ftp y el cliente acceda regularmente a ver si dicho archivo tiene actualizaciones, y a raíz de esto, mi segunda cuestión es: tener que hacer que el cliente revise información periódicamente no es ineficiente?, es decir los chats, como puedan ser whattsap  que utilizan? Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: ¿Esperas tener el mismo número de usuarios que WhatsApp? El diseño de aplicaciones consiste en escoger la solución adecuada al problema; WhatsApp tiene que lidiar con mucho más tráfico pero tiene muchos más recursos (programadores) para usar soluciones más complicadas, y soportar diferentes entornos (no sé que usa WhatsApp, pero Android tiene un servicio "pull" para envio de notificaciones). Y hoy en día, con tarifas planas de líneas terrestres y Mbps y demás, una conexión cada poco minutos no se nota.

Comment: ¿Cuántos clientes habrá?¿Con qué urgencia tiene que llegar la información al cliente?¿Tiene el cliente que configurar su red?¿Sabe hacerlo?¿Qué pasa si su IP cambia durante la sesión (puede pasar)?¿Cuánto tiempo dispones para cambiar la arquitectura de tu sistema de cliente-servidor a P2P?¿Qué otras cosas dejarás de hacer en ese tiempo?

Comment: Digamos unos 5.000 usuarios, seria un chat instantaneo asi que convendria pasar la informacion rapidamente, y no se espera que el cliente sepa configurar la red asi que tiene que ser automatico, el tema de la ip dinamica (no se si se llama asi) aun no me he metido en ello asi por ahora considerare que la ip es fija y ya lo ire modificando cuando estudie mas cosas, en cuanto al tiempo no es problema, soy estudiante y esto es por gusto y para aplicarlo como una caracteristica a un proyecto que tengo en mente, asi que si P2P es mejor para estos menesteres me pongo a estudiarlo. Un saludo.

Comment: :-). No he dicho que yo fuera a hacer tu diseño. Solo estaba poniendo un ejemplo de una (muy pequeña) parte de las cosas a considerar cuando tú hagas el tuyo.

Comment: En el proyecto que tengo planeado integrarlo los usuarios hablarian casi siempre en grupos mas que en privado y tendria que haber informacion como imagenes y texto al que pudieran acceder siempre que iniciaran sesion asi que al menos un servidor para almacenar esas cosas tiene que haber sino al desconectarse el peer que las almacenara los demas no podrian acceder

Comment: Claro nunca he pedido eso, es decir quiero aprender a hacerlo yo, solo queria saber si este sistema de socket cliente-servidor en el que el cliente tiende un socket con el servidor y el servidor se dedica a enrrutar los mensajes a traves de los sockets que tiene con los clientes es una opcion que pudiera funcionar o si deberia pensar otra cosa

Comment: A lo que quiero llegar con esto es a conocer mas o menos como funcionan estos sistemas de redes a nivel de saber cuanta eficiencia me puede dar para lo que busco, no quiero hacer algo que por ejemplo se desmonte cuando se conecten 100 usuarios por que el servidor o el cliente tiene que realizar demasiadas operaciones, esto no es, creo yo, como por ejemplo hacer un algoritmo para ordenar un vector que lo pones en marcha y cuando acaba puedes calcular su rendimiento, aquí necesitaría gente conectándose para ver si la arquitectura es estable